# DateTimeFormatter not working as expected with JODA

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I'm having troubles getting the correct format for a DateTime. I'm expecting format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss and I'm getting too much verbose instead. For instance:

```
        DateTime dt;
        String timeStamp = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":00"; 
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        dt = formatter.parseDateTime(timeStamp);
```

And I'm getting things like:

```
2013-06-13T00:15:00.000+02:00
```

Thus, why is the formatter not formatting as expected? Any clues?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Um, because you have `dt = new DateTime()` and have therefore not saved any use of the formatter? Also, what are you using to output the `DateTime` to get this result? Show that code.

Comment: The last line is a copy&paste error, I'm obviously not recreating the object there again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You told the formatter how to read your hand-crafted `timeStamp` String. You did not tell your system how to output the resulting `DateTime` object.

As Daniel Arndt pointed out below, you do that like this:

```
System.out.println(dt.toString(formatter));
```

Understand that a `DateTime` object has no format. The format is what turns a string into a `DateTime` object, and a `DateTime` object into a string. What you see on your screen are always strings. So if you do an output of your `DateTime` object, as above, you also need to tell the sytem how to format it. If you do not, it will use a system specific default format, which is what happened when you got the `2013-06-13T00:15:00.000+02:00` string.

Long story short: Your `DateTime` object contains the correct data. And if you provide the proper format, it will look exactly like you expect, when you output it.

Comment: Aha, any idea how to do that?

Comment: @AlejandroVK I just edited my answer with more information. Hope that helps.

Comment: That was my understanding, just wanted to be sure, thanks, correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are only using the formatter for parsing, not formatting.  If you used it for formatting as well e.g. with the [print()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#print%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) method you would see the string you expect.

Also you appear to be parsing the string and immediately replacing it with the current date time. I would remove you last line or all the lines before it.

Comment: Thank, but...I don't want a String at the end, I want to keep the DateTime object, since its a member of a data class, thus, if I inspect the resulting DateTime object...but I guess I'll have to change it to String instead and discard using DateTime

Comment: @AlejandroVK A DateTime is a date and a time, it doesn't have a format.  When you try to print it just uses the default format for that type.  Only a String has a format but it is just a bunch of characters.  You shouldn't confuse a bunch of characters with a value which represents a time, or number as they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
dt = new DateTime();
```

replaces all your efforts put by you before.So please remove it and print the `dt`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that was a copy & paste error, my mistake

Comment: Nope, not fixed, proposed solutions only depict returning a String, which I don't want, a need a DateTime with dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss format...

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the date with the formatter. The following code should work if you preform it before the `dt = new DateTime();` line:

```
System.out.println(dt.toString(formatter));
```